# ERROR-Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Application Insights Pl

Tags: azure, eclipse, installation, toolkit

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Application Insights Plugin for Java 3.31.0.202205311349 (com.microsoft.applicationinsights.feature.feature.group 3.31.0.202205311349)
  Missing requirement: Azure Core Plugin Library 3.31.0.202205311349 (com.microsoft.azuretools.core 3.31.0.202205311349) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Application Insights Plugin for Java 3.31.0.202205311349 (com.microsoft.applicationinsights.feature.feature.group 3.31.0.202205311349)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.microsoft.applicationinsights.ui [3.31.0.202205311349,3.31.0.202205311349]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Application Insights Plugin for Java 3.31.0.202205311349 (com.microsoft.applicationinsights.ui 3.31.0.202205311349)
    To: osgi.bundle; com.microsoft.azuretools.core 3.31.0
```

installed latest eclipse.
jdk is pesent.

following-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-eclipse/installation

Comment: It is looking for a "mylyn" plug-in which is no longer included with Eclipse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mylyn from eclipse marketplace before the azure toolkit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).